# Undesired Result in std::list removing (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am encountering some strange behaviour with my usage of std::list. The issue is that when I remove the current element in the list, it invalidates that element. When I am going through the elements with a `for( auto& iter : list)` loop, it gets stuck on the element that was supposed to be removed. I have a minimal compilable example to show this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>
    #include <memory>
    int main() {
        std::list<unsigned int> wholeNumbers;
        while( wholeNumbers.size() < 20 ) {
            wholeNumbers.push_back( wholeNumbers.size() );
        }
        for( auto wholeNumber : wholeNumbers ) {
            std::cout << "Deleting entries. Value is: " << wholeNumber << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Old size: " << wholeNumbers.size() << std::endl;
            wholeNumbers.remove( wholeNumber );
            std::cout << "New size: " << wholeNumbers.size() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

The desired result of this is to spew out the incrementing values, and the decrementing size. However, the result that I am experiencing is the following:

```
Deleting entries. Value is: 0
Old size: 20
New size: 19
Deleting entries. Value is: 0
Old size: 19
New size: 19
Deleting entries. Value is: 0
Old size: 19
New size: 19
Deleting entries. Value is: 1901208
Old size: 19
New size: 19
Deleting entries. Value is: 0
Old size: 19
New size: 19
Deleting entries. Value is: 0
Old size: 19
New size: 19
Deleting entries. Value is: 0
Old size: 19
New size: 19
Deleting entries. Value is: 1901208
Old size: 19
New size: 19
```

This then repeats indefinitely.

My compiler information is: `gcc version 5.3.0 (x86_64-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`

I'm curious if I am mistaken in believing that this should work as I intend.

Best regards,

Comment: You're invalidating your iterator.

Comment: Ah. Seeing your comment, it finally clued in. When I am removing it, it becomes invalidated and cannot move on to the next as, as the pointer no longer exits in the element. Therefore, removing elements should be done in a `remove_if` statement, instead of within a `for` loop. Thank you.

Comment: Spot on. Nice conclusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase :

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

The range based for loop uses an implicit iterator. `remove` is erasing the element pointed at by the iterator, so it becomes invalid and you have undefined behavior and it could wipe your hard drive.

Instead, get an explicit iterator. Call `erase`, not `remove`, and set the iterator to the return value of `erase` to continue iterating (return value: "Iterator following the last removed element.")

Comment: As I said in reply to erip in the comments, it clued in once I was told that the iterator is invalidated. Thanks for the heads up on the `erase` method to continue iterating!

Answer (score 1):

[list::remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/)

> Iterator validity: Iterators, pointers and references referring to elements removed by the function are invalidated.

Range based for loops use iterators internally, so what you do invalidates the iterator, and thus the behavior you expect is not what you can expect.

Unlike [std::remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/?kw=remove), which merely moves the elements to the end of the container and returns a pointer to the first one "removed" - thus requiring the famous erase-remove-idiom - list::remove actually calls the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration, you successfully removed the first element, along with the connection between the first element and the second element of the std::list. So it got a problem in the second iteration, because the for-loop could not set `auto wholeNumber` that is pointing to a deleted element with undefined value, to the second element of std::list.